# Remote Desktop Solution for Ubuntu 22.04, Wayland, RDP, and session management

Tags: gnome, software-rec, wayland, gdm, rdp

I've been looking for a Remote Desktop solution for Ubuntu 22.04.

'gnome-remote-desktop', Ubuntu 22.04's standard RDP solution, automatically quits when the user logs out and it does not support login session.

xRDP, on the other hand, is independent of the session managers such as GDM, but is not compatible with Wayland.

RealVNC does support GDM session manager and works with user logout, but it only supports VNC protocol, does not support wayland, and requires a RealVNC company network connection to use.

Is there any remote desktop solution which supports user session management, Wayland, and preferably RDP?

Comment: KRDC ? https://apps.kde.org/krdc/

Comment: I've been looking for an answer to this question as well. Unfortunately, I haven't found anything and it doesn't look like gnome-remote-desktop is about to get fuller functionality either: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3212